# Java Custom Web layout

Tags: java, layout, web

Currently i am developing a CRM web applications using J2EE . For this application i need to support the localization for the layout such as menu names.

At the same time i need to allow admin to customize the layout such as adding new menu or deleting the menu and changing themes. I am planned to use XML for the layout specifications
Anyother methods to achieve this one?

Please help me . 
Thanks in advance
Dilip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that If you use an XML you have to write your Parsers to read/write the settings updated by the users which will be time consuming and may be complicated.
I would suggest to use Database and put these Menus in master tables. Then you can create a table (for many to many relationship with menus and users) which contains the settings updated by the user. At the login or before generating the menus, you can get the menus specific to that user and display it as per your requirement. You can do the same for Themes.
I think, this would be bit easier and readable too.

Comment: Any methods are currently available in java to achieve this

Comment: There is no such method available in Java, however, it will be as similar as you are communicating the database with simple JDBC statements.

Comment: Is this XSLT is the best option to define the layout?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Customization / Personalization, not Localization. Customization / Personalization involves a lot of work. There are special frameworks such as [Oracle's WebCenter Framework](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/webcenter.1111/e10147/Topic_5.1.htm) that are proficient at this. If you get into writing this customization framework yourself, you will be developing and maintaining a lot of plumbing which will take time away from implementing real business functionality. I suggest that you do not re-invent the wheel and try to re-use an out of the box framework.